# Change header of all text files in directory in commandline

Tags: command-line

I have tons of *.csv measurement files with following header:

```
Start time: Thu Oct 09 15:46:16 CST 2014 
Trend type: Average Wavelength over [259.09, 259.09] 
Trend offset: None 
>>>>>Begin Strip Chart Data<<<<<
Date    Elapsed Time    Absorbance(Absorbance)
```

How can I change this with command-line in the whole directory to following header:

```
Date    ElapsedTime Absorbance
```

Cheers,

Hans

Comment: To clarify: you want to strip off the first 4 lines of each file? Or all lines before "Date    Elapsed Time    Absorbance(Absorbance)"?

Answer (score 1):

This will remove first four lines form `csv` files and remove "(Absorbance)" part from them:

```
find . -name  "*\.csv" -exec \
    bash -c "tail -n +5 {} |
                 sed 's/Absorbance(Absorbance)/Absorbance/' |
                 sed 's/Elapsed Time/ElapsedTime/' > {}.bak |
                 mv {}.bak {}" \;
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me at least one day of copy and paste!! The only thing left is to remove the space in "Elapsed Time" to get "ElapsedTime". I tried it with sed but the result was a empty file (because I have no idea of apple skript ;)

Comment: I've eddited my answer. But If You have already run this command, remove `tail` because You'll lose first 4 lines in every csv file.

Comment: @Hans note this is not AppleScript but Unix shell script